# To remove an instance of the list

Tags: apex, visualforce

Visual Page code

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AddAircrfatController">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:form id="frmId">
        <table>
            <apex:repeat value="{!aircraftList}" var="aircraft">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Base Airport: <apex:inputField value="{!aircraft.BaseAirport__c}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Capacity: <apex:inputField value="{!aircraft.Capacity__c}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Manufacturer: <apex:inputField value="{!aircraft.Manufacturer__c}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Number of Engines: <apex:inputField value="{!aircraft.Number_of_Engines__c}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Remove" action="{!remove}" rerender="frmId" immediate="true"/>
                    </td>                   
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </table>
        <apex:commandButton value="Add Aircraft" action="{!addAircraft}" rerender="frmId" immediate="true"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save Aircraft" action="{!saveAircraft}"/>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Code

```
public class AddAircrfatController {

    public List<Aircraft__c> aircraftList {get;set;}

    private Id airLineId {get;set;}

    public AddAircrfatController(ApexPages.StandardController std) {
        aircraftList = new List<Aircraft__c>();
        Aircraft__c aircraft = new Aircraft__c();
        aircraft.Airline__c = std.getId();
        aircraftList.add(aircraft);
        airLineId = std.getId();
    }

    public void addAircraft() {
        Aircraft__c aircraft = new Aircraft__c();
        aircraft.Airline__c = airLineId;
        aircraftList.add(aircraft);
    }

    public void remove() {
         aircraftList.clear(aircraft);
    }

    public void saveAircraft() {
        //system.debug('aircraft:'+aircraft);
        insert aircraftList;
        //system.debug('aircraft1:'+aircraft);
    }
}
```

[image]

Hi I am new to salesforce
can anyone help me wats the code to remove the instance of the list when we click on the remove button
Thank you

Comment: is that my answer solved your purpose?

Answer (score 2):

To remove the item from the list, you need to use the row index.

**Apex**

```
public Integer rowNum{get;set;}
    public void remove() {
         rowNum = Integer.valueOf(apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('index'));
         aircraftList.remove(rowNum);  
    }
```

**Visualforce**

Declare `rowNum` as `apex:variable`, increment that in the loop and pass the `rownum` as a parameter to `remove()` method.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AddAircrfatController">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:form id="frmId">
        <table>
            <apex:repeat value="{!aircraftList}" var="aircraft">
                <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!0}"/>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Base Airport: <apex:inputField value="{!aircraft.BaseAirport__c}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Capacity: <apex:inputField value="{!aircraft.Capacity__c}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Manufacturer: <apex:inputField value="{!aircraft.Manufacturer__c}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Number of Engines: <apex:inputField value="{!aircraft.Number_of_Engines__c}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Remove" action="{!remove}" reRender="frmId" immediate="true>
                           <apex:param value="{!rowNum}" name="index"/>
                        </apex:commandButton>
                    </td>                   
                </tr>
                <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
            </apex:repeat>
        </table>
        <apex:commandButton value="Add Aircraft" action="{!addAircraft}" rerender="frmId" immediate="true"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save Aircraft" action="{!saveAircraft}"/>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```